# Add post with approval by the admin

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles

Is it possible in Woocommerce to add products only as draft or pending status if user role is not admin? and only the admin could publish the post.

Answer (score 2):

Set **New User Default Role** to **Contributor**. Change user role of existing users as well, if needed.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Add this to your `functions.php` file. It'll allow your contributor and author users to add WooCommerce products.
And then set default user role to contributor as I suggested before.

```
function wpse_306836_wc_custom_permission( $args, $post_type ) {

   if ( 'product' === $post_type ) {
      $args['capability_type'] = 'post';
   }

   return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse_306836_wc_custom_permission', 10, 2 );
```

Please note, some features like creating taxonomies, assigning them, uploading media files etc won't work. You need to change permission for these as well.

Comment: thanks but I forgot that I have woocommerce installed and the contributor doesn't allow to add products, how to enable user role to add products in pending status like contributor does.

Comment: I don't think you want to allow new users to add WooCommerce products! Products should be added by administrator or editor users only, which must be created manually.
So I don't see any problem with my previous solution.

Comment: The questioner might be running a marketplace style site where people can post items for sale. @mukto90

Comment: so how could I put approval/pending of added products? because my client is asking to put approval, and the admin will receive notification of new products added, then he/she will publish it.

Comment: Just updated my answer.